# How do you debug MinGW exception handling?

Tags: c++, exception, mingw

I have an utterly baffling problem with a C++ program I'm compiling with MinGW. At a certain, deterministic point in the program some exception handlers get disabled, and any future exceptions thrown are no longer handled. I can track down the precise line of source that does this, it's an inoffensive assignment to an array on the heap. The pointer isn't corrupt, nor am I writing beyond its bounds. What's more the same code is called in a bunch of different circumstances, even with most of the same arguments without triggering the bug. If I fiddle with the code to make the value it writes always zero, the bug is never triggered. I'm at a loss to know what's happening. It also only disables some exception handlers. exception handlers further down the callstack get disabled, while ones higher up stay active. It's baffling.

So, how do should I go about debugging this? I really don't have a good grasp of how exceptions actually work in MinGW's version of GCC. What could be happening to cause this weird set of symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, turns out that taking some time out and thinking about the symptoms suggested the answer.

Turns out a terrible library I'm using can throw an exception during cleanup, so I was getting an exception within an exception during stack unwinding.

I should have realised that when handlers further up the call stack behaved properly. Duh.